# Ввести с клавиатуры три целых числа. Вывести на экран количество положительных чисел среди этих трех

Tags: java

Задание:

> Положительное число Ввести с клавиатуры три целых числа. Вывести на
> экран количество положительных чисел среди этих трех.
>
> Примеры:
>
> 1. при вводе чисел -4 6 6 получим вывод 2
> 2. при вводе чисел
>    -6
>    -6
>    -3 получим вывод 0 в) при вводе чисел 0 1 2 получим вывод 2
>
> Требования:

> 1. Программа должна считывать числа c клавиатуры.
> 2. Программа должна выводить число на экран.
> 3. Программа должна выводить количество положительных чисел в исходном наборе.
> 4. Если положительных чисел нет, программа должна вывести "0".
> 5. Учти, что "0" не относится ни к положительным, ни к отрицательным числам.

Мое решение (как мне кажется правильное):

```
   public static int proverka(int n) {
      int x = 0;
      while (n > 0) {
         x = 1;
      }
      return x;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int a = sc.nextInt();
      int b = sc.nextInt();
      int c = sc.nextInt();
      sc.close();
      System.out.println(proverka(a) + proverka(b) + proverka(c));

   }

}
```

Вопрос: почему не работает, почему я ввожу три числа а он не выводит количество положительных чисел?

Comment: а что не работает?

Comment: замените `while` на `if`, цикл `while` никогда не закончится если число отрицательное

Comment: Поди зависает, ежели хоть одно положительное ввести? proverka(int n) смотри, там косяк, while не по делу.

Comment: а, бесконечный цикл, ну так вы не меняете n

Comment: @Komdosh зависает наверняка =)

Comment: Я просто ввожу три числа и все, то есть как будто бы процесс ввода числа бесконечный... думаете зависло просто? сейчас попробую на if изменить

Comment: @Foxy0404 вы знаете про существование отладчика? он бы тут помог =)

Comment: Спасибушки Господа) все заработало с IF)))) я просто еще не сильна в циклах)

Comment: Нет, про отладчика не в курсе, я только месяц занимаюсь и пока не обо всем знаю..

Comment: вы код в среде разработки пишете?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> while (n > 0) {
> ```

```
if (n > 0) {
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/465058)

Comment: @hedgehogues, а если подумать?

Comment: Не признал (ещё 5 символов)